# C format strings get truncated in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, java-native-interface, string-formatting, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I have the following line of C code to format degrees/minutes/seconds as a string.

```
g_strdup_printf("%d°%d'%d\" %c%c%d°%d'%d\" %c",
    lat_deg,lat_min,lat_sec,latc,sep,lng_deg,lng_min,lng_sec,lngc);
```

The code is part of a cross-platform app which runs on a couple of platforms, including Linux and Android. Starting with Android Lollipop, the string gets truncated at the first degree sign. Instead of `42°43'44" N 45°46'47" E` I just get `42`. Indeed `strlen` reports the string as being 2 characters long.

This code has worked flawlessly on earlier Android versions (at least Gingerbread through KitKat). It also works on Linux, and in the past I have used it successfully on Windows CE and desktop Windows.

What's happening on Lollipop, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Lollipop has issues with extended characters (anything in excess of 7 bits) in a C format string:

When I replace the degree signs with spaces, the result is as expected. When I replace them with any other character from the extended ANSI set, they get truncated as if that character were `\0` – same if I use proper escape sequences like `\xb0` or `\u00b0`. So apparently it's extended ANSI characters that give us trouble.

When I do

```
g_strdup_printf("42°43'44\" N 45°46'47\" E");
```

I get a correctly formatted string. So apparently the issue affects only string formatting routines, not generic string stuff – which also explains why coordinates in static strings would work.

Adding placeholders in the format string for the degree signs and passing them as extra arguments also didn't help – they would show as mojibake and crash the rendering code.

I ended up bypassing the string formatting routines altogether and doing:

```
g_strjoin(NULL,
        g_strdup_printf("%d", lat_deg), "°",
        g_strdup_printf("%d", lat_min), "'",
        g_strdup_printf("%d", lat_sec), "\" ",
        g_strnfill(1, latc),
        g_strnfill(1, sep),
        g_strdup_printf("%d", lng_deg), "°",
        g_strdup_printf("%d", lng_min), "'",
        g_strdup_printf("%d", lng_sec), "\" ",
        g_strnfill(1, lngc),
        NULL);
```

Comment: Oh this hurts. Hope they will fix this. Have you opened an issue on [google tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list)?